# Remove string from end of line using awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file of data of the format

```
alpha/beta/gamma/beta 0.2
alpha/beta/gamma/beta/gamma 0.2
alpha/beta/gamma/beta/alpha/alpha 0.2 ...
```

I want the output to be:

```
alpha/beta/gamma 0.2
alpha/beta/gamma/beta 0.2 
alpha/beta/gamma/beta/alpha 0.2 ....
```

Essentially take each line and remove all the characters from the end of `$1` after the last `/`.

```
{
sed 's/ & \/*$//'
}
```

Comment: Hello. Stack overflow is about helping programmers solving programming problems. This is a task request - and one that's pretty straight forward. So I would ask - what have you tried so far, and why is that not working? Please see [ask] for what makes a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$ sed 's|/[^/]* | |' infile
alpha/beta/gamma 0.2
alpha/beta/gamma/beta 0.2
alpha/beta/gamma/beta/alpha 0.2
```

This uses the pipe `|` as a delimiter so we don't have to escape `/`. The substitution matches a slash followed by zero or more non-slashes (`/[^/]*`) and a space, then replaces that with a space, effectively removing the last slash and what follows it up to the space.

Comment: Your solution works great when I use it in the command line. When I input the whole file it does not give me the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ME510 What do you mean with "input the whole file", as opposed to "in the command line"?

Comment: when i use echo string | sed ... the code works. when I use $ sed 's|/[^/]* | |' infile it returns the exact same file as output

Comment: So it prints the unmodified file to stdout, or it prints the proper modifications but doesn't change the actual file?

Comment: prints the unmodified to stdout

Comment: @ME510 That's weird, it works here. If you do something nonsensical like `sed 's/.*/X/' infile`, does it also just print the input file unmodified?

Comment: It just prints out Xs.

Comment: This means sed works, but `sed 's|/[^/]* | |' infile` doesn't work for you? Do you have all the single quotes properly?

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me. I had a tab instead of space in my file which was causing this problem. I changed it to space and it works well now. Thanks for your help,again.

Answer (score 1):

sed probably would work better than awk:

```
sed 's/\/[a-z]* / /' file
```

Comment: This would remove the string from the end? This does not seem to work. I tried  sed -e 's/\/[a-z]*$ / / that does not work either

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{sub("/[^/]+","",$1)} 1' file
alpha/gamma/beta 0.2
alpha/gamma/beta/gamma 0.2
alpha/gamma/beta/alpha/alpha 0.2 ...
```